# Default value for next element in Python iterator if iterator is empty?

Tags: python, iterator

I have a list of objects, and I would like to find the first one for which a given method returns true for some input value.  This is relatively easy to do in Python:

```
pattern = next(p for p in pattern_list if p.method(input))
```

However, in my application it is common that there is no such `p` for which `p.method(input)` is true, and so this will raise a `StopIteration` exception.  Is there an idiomatic way to handle this without writing a try/catch block?

In particular, it seems like it would be cleaner to handle that case with something like an `if pattern is not None` conditional, so I'm wondering if there's a way to expand my definition of `pattern` to provide a `None` value when the iterator is empty -- or if there's a more Pythonic way to handle the overall problem!

Answer (score 101, accepted):

[`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) accepts a default value:

```
next(...)
    next(iterator[, default])

    Return the next item from the iterator. If default is given and the iterator
    is exhausted, it is returned instead of raising StopIteration.
```

and so

```
>>> print next(i for i in range(10) if i**2 == 9)
3
>>> print next(i for i in range(10) if i**2 == 17)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> print next((i for i in range(10) if i**2 == 17), None)
None
```

Note that you have to wrap the genexp in the extra parentheses for syntactic reasons, otherwise:

```
>>> print next(i for i in range(10) if i**2 == 17, None)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument
```